# Creating Variable Constraints for a UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to make some UIImageViews in Xcode that fill the screen based on different conditions. For example, I might have a 3x3 square of images that have to fill the screen, or a 4x4 square that must fill the screen, based on different initial conditions. Every time I try to accomplish this, the ImageViews just end up being the same size for both conditions. I've tried many different solutions but the one I'm currently trying is:

```
    if fieldDimensions == 3 {
        let spacing = screenWidth / 16
        let boxsize = screenWidth / 4
        let xadjust = spacing / 2 //Value to help align view
        let interval = spacing + boxsize

        Button1Image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button1height.constant = boxsize
        button1width.constant = boxsize
        button2height.constant = boxsize
        button2width.constant = boxsize

    }
    else if fieldDimensions == 4 {
        let spacing = screenWidth / 20
        let boxsize = screenWidth * 3/16
        let interval = spacing + boxsize

        button1height.constant = boxsize
        button1width.constant = boxsize
        button2height.constant = boxsize
        button2width.constant = box size
```

All of the button heights and widths are linked to the height and width constraints in the storyboard (I just control-dragged them). Any help would be really appreciated, I've been working on this problem for almost a week now, thanks!!

Comment: Seems like you might want a `UICollectionView` or nested `UIStackView`s instead?

Comment: Any time you have variable names like `button1`, `button2`, etc. it's a clue that you should be using some sort of collection object

Comment: Also, remember that UIButton won't automatically resize your images for you. You may need to resize the `UIImage` itself, or adjust the `contentMode` on each button's image view.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys! Regardless of whether or not the images are in an array, how can I create constraints that can change in different scenarios? And I apologize, the images used to be buttons, but I changed them, that's why the constraint names are wrongly labeled "button1height" etc... they are all UIImageViews, not UIButtons

Comment: I suspect that your image views *are* changing size, but you haven't changed the `contentMode` property so they still draw the images at the default size